# mysql group by and having clause getting error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error on the following query even though everything seems fine on my end:

```
SELECT
    user.*
FROM
    user
INNER JOIN
    role ON role.id = user.role_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    user_documents ON user.id = user_documents.user_id 
WHERE
    user.id = 1
GROUP BY
    user.id 
HAVING
    count(user_documents.user_id) < role.max_allowed_documents
```

The error I get is `Unknown column 'role.max_allowed_documents' in 'having clause'` but I triple checked and that column exists in my role table. Any ideas?

Basically I have users assigned to roles. Each user may have a number of documents defined in the roles table by `max_allowed_documents` which is an integer and this query tries to select all users that are still allowed to have documents (didn't reached their limit).

Answer (score 5):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in
>   the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However,
>   MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and **permits HAVING to
>   refer to columns in the SELECT list** and columns in outer subqueries as
>   well.

Following code should be fine:

```
SELECT
    user.*, role.max_allowed_documents
FROM
    user
INNER JOIN
    role ON role.id = user.role_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    user_documents ON user.id = user_documents.user_id 
WHERE
    user.id = 1
GROUP BY
    user.id 
HAVING
    count(user_documents.user_id) < role.max_allowed_documents
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      user.*
   FROM
      user
         JOIN role 
            ON user.role_id = role.id
         LEFT JOIN
            ( select ud.user_id, count(*) as DocCount 
                 from user_documents ud
                 group by ud.user_id ) PreCounted
            on user.id = PreCounted.user_id
   WHERE
      COALESCE( PreCounted.DocCount, 0 ) < role.max_allowed_documents
```